# Finding a nonempty subset that is not a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

### Question:

Give an example of a group $G$ having a subset $H$ such that $HH=H$, where $HH = \left\{h_1h_2\mid h_1,h_2\in H \right\}$, but $H$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

### Attempted Solution:

I haven't gotten far with this problem. In a previous exercise, I was able to prove that $HH=H$ if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. I am having a hard time thinking of a scenario where $h_1h_2\in H$ and $H$ is not a group. I've played around with making $h_1h_2$ not closed under its operation, but I haven't gotten anywhere yet.

Comment: Sufficient to find a non-empty subset that is not closed under taking the inverse.

Comment: or just note that $\: H = \{\} \:$ will work. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Such a group cannot be a finite group. What infinite groups do you know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G=\mathbb {R} \setminus \{0\}$ with multiplication and $H=(0,1]$

Answer (score 2):

This set $H$ can lack inverses. Let $G = \mathbb Z$ and $H = \mathbb N_0$ (operation is addition).

Comment: To be sure I understand: this works because $\mathbb{N}_0$ excludes the inverses; in particular, the negative integers.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the point.

Answer (score 2):

Take the group  $G$ as $\mathbb Z$ with addition and the subgroup $H$ as set of all even positive integers. $H$ is closed under addition but doesn't have inverse so $H$ is not a subgroup

Comment: If $H$ is even integers closed under addition, doesn't each element have an inverse? Namely $-h$ for $h\in H$?

Comment: You are correct , I have corrected my answer.