# example for not being a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Be $G$ a group with subgroups $U$ and $V$ and be $UV := \left\{uv \mid u \in U, v \in V \right\}$

I want to prove the following:

> $UV$ is in general no subgroup of $G$.

Proof. Be $U \nsubseteq V$ and $V \nsubseteq U$. Be $x \in U \setminus V$ and $y \in V \setminus U$.

Hence $xy \in UV$ but $xy \notin U \cup V$. This implies $\left(xy \right)\left(xy\right) \notin UV$ per definition of $UV$, hence $UV$ is no subgroup of $G \quad \square$

But I also want to give an explicit counterexample beside this proof. Could you give me a hint in which group I should look for the easiest counterexample?

Comment: I remember it being asked yesterday. Did you search for it?

Comment: [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1529881/45937) you go.

Comment: Your proof can't be correct since it is sometimes a subgroup. In particular "This implies $(xy)(xy) \notin UV$" is not necessarily true.

Comment: That's why I wrote 'in general'. And with $xy \in UV$ and $xy \notin U \cup V$ it implies $(xy)(xy) \notin UV$ indeed.

Comment: @swizzor, unless proof is demanded, in a situation where you just have to prove the statement is not always true, a counter example is a proof enough!

Comment: @JessePFrancis, I know that a counterexample is enough, but for my own understanding I wanted to find out what is needed to create a counterexample

Comment: at the mentioned link there are no examples of two subgroups whose   product isn't a subgroup, so the OP question hadn't be answered until now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take $S_3$ the symmetric group on three labels.

If $S_3=\{1\!\!1,(12),(13),(23),(123),(321)\}$ then take
$U=\{1\!\!1,(12)\}$ and $V=\{1\!\!1,(13)\}$. They are subgroups.

You will see that $UV$ is not a subgroup.